# Recover unbootable Ubuntu, boot-partition gone?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, mbr, chroot

I was unable to boot Ubuntu after setting my BIOS to default. I tried Boot-repair and tried a "recommended repair". After a while it asks me to insert the following in Terminal:

sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" dpkg --configure -a

sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" apt-get install -fy

sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub* shim-signed linux-signed*

Than I get an error saying: Grub still present, try again. Boot-info gives the following output:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8429040

Does this output look "healthy" to you, or do I miss my boot-partition? Does anyone know how I can make my Ubuntu bootable again?

Comment: How about `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 1):

You do not have grub installed in your MBR.

You can simply re-install grub from a live cd.

The process is a bit complicated, involves mounting a few partitions and installing grub.

Give [this](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/10/installrecover-grub-from-linux-live-cd.html) a try and keep us posted on your results.

Comment: With UEFI you do not install grub to the gpt protective MBR unless you want to boot in Legacy/BIOS boot mode. You should be able to boot in UEFI boot mode. Unless you want the signed versions for secure boot you should not need to install those. What vendor/model system? Some vendors modify UEFI to only boot Windows and we have to create work arounds like rename grub to look like Windows or copy grub into the hard drive boot entry (which you do not yet have). http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: @oldfred, he said BIOS didn't he?

Comment: He may have said BIOS and many still call UEFI BIOS as it also has a BIOS boot mode called CSM. But Boot Summary shows efi partition and efi boot files for UEFI boot. Many users are not sure of configuration and we have to review things like Boot-Repair's summary report to really know how system is configured.

Comment: @oldfred, Zeus77, thank you for your reply. I have an Acer Aspire X3995, which ran Ubuntu fine until loading the default settings of BIOS to default. I will have a crack at it, and let you know!

Comment: If you reset UEFI/BIOS to defaults that reverses all the changes you may have made. I found when I updated my BIOS it reset everything back to defaults and all sorts of things stopped working. I had to take photos of each BIOS screen so I could remember settings.

Comment: @Zeus77 I tried it and got stuck at step 5:

grub-install /dev/sda2

grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.

I also tried sudo update-grub, which gives:

/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.

Comment: @RobLamb did you mount everything properly as mentioned in the article?

Comment: @Zeus77 Yes, I did but still no effect. I have been trying to figure it out for almost two weeks and decided to go back to Windows again, because it takes a bit to much of my time and I am afraid that in the end I will do more harm then good since it is a rather new PC. Thank you ever so much for your efforts to help!